# Conditional restart on Activity onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, android-activity, restart, onconfigurationchanged

I want to make an activity that allows orientation changes on some condition, but not otherwise. More exactly I want to prevent restarting the activity when a background thread is busy.

I have put the `configChanges` attribute on the activity manifest, and `onConfigurationChanged` is called when the orientation changes. However I want to allow the app to change the orientation **when allowed**.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (orientationChangeAllowed) {
        // how do I restart this activity?
    } else {
        // don't do anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if it's allowed call `setRequestedOrientation()`, when it's not allowed, do nothing.

As a tip: You can use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` and return (an object containing) the `AsyncThread`. This way the `Activity` will change orientation when the user wants to. Take note though: You shouldn't leak a reference to a `Context` (may it be a reference to your `Activity` or a `Drawable`, ...).